# Fast Forward Laplace transform

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

There are examples for fast numerical inversion of the Laplace transforms. For example here:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32824-numerical-inversion-of-laplace-transforms-in-matlab

My question is: are there implementations of Fast Laplace transform?
For example if one takes and array of values $[a_1 \ldots a_n] $ and transforms then to  $[b_1 \ldots b_n] $.

Comment: Isn't the thing you linked to an implementation?  So the answer is "yes".

Comment: Please make difference between a forward an inverse transform. My question is about the forward transform.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: Based on a very quick skim, the linked implementation does not appear to be "fast", since the algorithm it implements (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1099-1204(199805/06)11:3%3C153::AID-JNM299%3E3.0.CO;2-C/abstract) does not make any claims about $O(N \log N)$ (or less) complexity.

Comment: The algorithm uses FFT and IFFT + a series expansion so it is approximately $O ( N log N)$